# Setting alternating row style on grideview + templates in c#

Tags: c#, templates, gridview, css

I'm working on a web application. And I need to databind some values to gridview, which i successfully do, BUT I have some issues...

Basically everything happens inside the code (c#) so there is direct page where i define the gridview etc ...

Here is the code:

```
        ResultTable searchResult=.... //Results

        gridSearchResults = new GridView();
        gridSearchResults.Width = Unit.Percentage(100.0);
        gridSearchResults.BorderWidth = 0;
        gridSearchResults.DataSource = resultsTable;
        gridSearchResults.DataBind();
```

Result table has following tables: Priority, Title, Date and Link.

When i bind everything i get a nice table, with all the needed data, BUT everything is text, but in my case i would like to have Title as link with the 'link that come from column Link in the results table' and yeah i would also want to reformat date.

How do i do that exactly?

Another thing is how do i set row style and alternating row style, the property seems to only be GET, how do i set it then?

I repeat again, everything should be in C# in the class happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define columns for the GridView. In your case, it sounds like to me that you would need a column that is of type `HyperLinkField`. In that class, you can specify the properties `DataNavigateUrlFields` and `DataTextField`.  The DataTextField allows you to specify the name of the field from the DataSource that contains the display text, which in your case sounds like it would be the Title column. The DataNavigateUrlFields allows you to specify the field(s) from the DataSource used to populate the URL - in your case it sounds like this would be the 'Link' column from the data source. I am not sure exactly how you are doing things, but the snippet below shows you how to add a HyperLink column to your GridView.  Based on the code you provided, it doesn't look like you were manually defining the columns to use, but if you want the required behavior you may have to manually define all the columns you need.

```c#
    HyperLinkField titleLinkField = new HyperLinkField();
    titleLinkField.DataTextField = "Title";  //Column name providing hyperlink title
    titleLinkField.DataNavigateUrlFields = "Link";  //Column providing the URL to use.

    gridSearchResults.Columns.Add(titleLinkField);
```

As far as defining alternating row styles, you can set properties within that property. You may set each property individually, or define a CSS class to use.

```c#
    gridSearchResults.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass = "myAlternatingClass";
    gridSearchResults.RowStyle.CssClass = "myRegularClass";
    // OR
    gridSearchResults.AlternatingRowStyle.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Blue;
    gridSearchResults.RowStyle.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green;
```

Edit: Paolo Tedesco beat me to it, and he did have one bit that I was missing. You do need to specify the AutoGenerateColumns to False on your GridView.

For regular fields, you should use basically the same as above, but instead of using HyperLinkField, you can use a BoundField.

Answer (score 1):

To get the data formatted as you want, you will have to create the columns explcitly:

```
gridSearchResults = new GridView { 
    AutoGenerateColumns=false,
    // other properties...
};
gridSearchResults.Columns.Add(new HyperLinkField {
    HeaderText = "MyLink",
    DataTextField = "MyField"
    // and so on
});
```

Then, `AlternatingRowStyle` is readonly, but you can set its individual properties:

```
gridSearchResults.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Comment: and what if i want normal field and not hyperlinkfield? And ofr that HyperLinkField, how can i get value from "Link"?

Comment: What do you mean with "normal"?